# What variables start with the character '_' according to java code convention?

Tags: java, coding-style

Saw several code listings in which some variable declaration starts with _. For example long _variable = 0;

What variables start with the character '_' according to java code convention?

Comment: Yes and what is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using underscores in Java variables and method names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150192/using-underscores-in-java-variables-and-method-names)

Answer (score 1):

Using an underscore in a java variable is not a good practice, unless it is a constant.
[See this question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150192/using-underscores-in-java-variables-and-method-names)

Also generally names starting with _ are sometimes used as system variables and there is no sense in starting your variable with _ .

Edit: [Question about constant naming conventions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519475/java-constant-variable-naming-convention)

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation that says that constants can be named with an underscore? That would be a good thing to add to your answer.

Comment: Hi, added a link to naming conventions question.